# iOS: how to get the initial position of the collectionview scrolled a few downstairs?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

Here is my actual collectionview:
[image]
We can see that the first line is cut.

How to get that result:
[image]

I would like that the scroll of my collectionview begins with a "y" in "y-10".

Here is the piece of code, but I need to detect when user scroll to the top of the collectionView:

```
slotCollectionView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: -10), animated: false)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What constraints do you have set?

Comment: @Scriptable I have no constraints